# prune recursive search paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, recursion, trie, pruning

my knowledge is limited, writing in C++ for 2 months

In this function `string code` is recursively decrements chars until the base case `""` is found. I want to prune some paths before the base case is found, and for some `string code` a path to the base case will not be found. For the prune I want to compare an attribute in the path with parameter `int time`. This searches a trie made of 'nodeT'

```
struct charT {
char letter;
nodeT *next;
};

struct nodeT {
bool isOperation;
bool isCode; 
int time;
Vector<charT> alpha;
};

nodeT *root

usage:
string code = "12345";
int time = convertToEpoch(20120815); //my epoch function
containsCode(code, time)

bool containsCode(string code, int time)
{
    if(root == NULL) return false;
    else return containsCodeHelper(root, code, time);
}


bool containsCodeHelper(nodeT *w, string code, int time)
{
    if(code == "") //base case: all char found
        return w->isCode; 
    else {
        if (w->isOperation && w->time != time) return false; //case 2: time check OK <- at a midpoint in the path
        for(int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) { //Loop through the leaf
            if (w->alpha[i].letter == code[0]) //case 3: leaf exists
                return containsCodeHelper(w->alpha[i].next, code.substr(1), time);
        }
    }
    return false; //if no path
}
```

This function worked well before adding the time check prune, it now loops, `returns false` if outside time but then starts again with the candidate `string code` from char location 0.

Questions: 1) Is a nested `return false` kicking the recursion back to the next call for loop, 2) should the time prune be placed in the for loop with a logical `return false` or `return` 'path', 3) is this more fundamentally messed-up and I need to learn a C++ concept <- please explain if yes.

Also, the posted function is a simplified version of the actual function - there is a modifier to time and a 'step over' path that I left out. In past question I found that these 'addons' distract from the question.

Comment: `string word`? `string code`?

Comment: @timrau fixed typo `string word` -> `string code`

Comment: In your recursion calls to `containsCodeHelper()`, you never updated the parameter `time`. Could you explain what `time` means?

Comment: epoch, more or less; I edited the question with the `containsCode` call

Comment: to check this function I placed breaks and followed the autos at each break - is there so many paths that I should just create a test case and let it go to see if the result is correct rather than step through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some reworking it now functions fine - possibly it always did; I changed to read attribute `return w->isCode` to `return true`, that seemed to be the biggest issue - I will debug the trie constructor and see if it is setting the attribute at the end of each path.

```
boolcontainsCodeHelper(nodeT *w, string code, int time) 
{
    if(code == "") //base case: all char found
        return true;
    else {
        if ( w->isOperation && (!((w->begin-wag) <= time && time <= (w->end+wag) ) && time != 9999 ) ) 
            return false; //case 2: time
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) { //Loop through all of the children of the current node
                if (w->alpha[i].letter == word[0])
                    return containsCodeHelper(w->alpha[i].next, word.substr(1), time, wag);
                else if (word[0] == 'ž') //step over '0' all subnodes
                    if (containsCodeHelper(w->alpha[i].next, word.substr(1), time, wag)) 
                        return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //if char is missing - meaning the exact code is not there - terminates garbage subnode paths
}
```

I don't see any difference between having `return false;` at the end and leaving it out. Also still confused as why the special case needs `if( bool fn()) return true;` rather than just `return ( bool fn());` i found that solution through trial and error with help from another [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873156/write-trie-parsing-recursive-function-with-node-step-over)